# how to get data data when payple is complete

Tags: php, paypal

I’m designing a Paypal checkout page. What I want to know is, let say a customer signup for an account and he wants to pay the money, it will take it to the paypal checkout page. but after checkout, how do i know if that specific person paid or not. I want to know if there is any way I can get a confirmaton from paypal to my website back so I can confirm his payment and give him access automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Use the Paypal IPN, [here's a nice tutorial on how to get started](http://designertuts.com/145/paypal-ipn-receiving-instant-payments-in-your-web-application) but you really have to read read read a lot of content before you get a good working system.